# Building front-end using Angular for someone else to build back-end later

Tags: angularjs, django, frontend, backend

I'm thinking about building front-end of my web application with Angular for someone else to build the back-end of it later using Django or ME(A)N or something else. I know building front-end with HTML, CSS and javascript and handing it over to back-end engineer works, but I'm not sure about Angular and I'd like to be cautious. Is this a good idea, or would it be preferred that both front-end and back-end be developed simultaneously? And does it matter whether backend is Django or ME(A)N or else?

If this is not in line with Stack Overflow policy, please do me the favor of answering before closing it.

Comment: All that matters is whether or not the server provides well-structured RESTful APIs.  As long as it does, it doesn't matter what the front end OR backend are written in.  As yes, this is off topic for Stack Overflow as it is both opinion-based AND too broad :).

Comment: @DavidL OK, thank you! I don't know what RESTful APIs are and how they matter and who should provide this but this seems like something I can find out easily with Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can develop your front-end independently with no concerns about how it will be implemented.
You can use Karma and Jasmine to unit test your Front-End code by mocking your API calls with fake responses or fake logic, and you can use Protractor to run End-to-End tests on your Front-End code, again mocking the backend with fake placeholder logic.
As long as you expose certain API to communicate with the front-end, it does not matter which one you implement from a Front-End point of view.